pg_basebackup: error: backup failed: ERROR: could not open file "./.pg_hba.conf.swp": Permission denied
I am getting this error:
pg_basebackup: error: backup failed: ERROR:
could not open file "./.pg_hba.conf.swp": Permission denied

Could you please shed some light on possible reasons?

Pretty clear the .pg_hba.conf.swp has permissions that don't match the user running pg_basebackup. Though the bigger issue is what .pg_hba.conf.swp is doing there? That looks like a left over file from a text editor(VIM?).

Database Administrators would be a better community for this question.

The problem is that you created a file in the data directory that the PostgreSQL user cannot read.
I guess you used to root user to edit pg_hba.conf with the vi editor, and the session got killed, so that a swap file stayed behind.
Remove the file, and don't use the root user for tasks that a normal user can do.
